# Не правильный вид ответа(новичок в node js)

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Пытаюсь объединить две таблицы, что бы в результате получился список постов + поле его категории. Объединение проходит успешно, но по какой-то причине данные из второй таблицы не приходят как объект. Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка.

Модели:

```
    const ModelPosts = conn.define(`posts`, {
    // определение атрибутов модели
    id_posts: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    descr: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    
});

const PostCategory = conn.define(`post_category`, {
    // определение атрибутов модели
    id_category: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    name_category: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
});
```

Связи между моделями (в phpmyadmin связи тоже прописаны):

```
PostCategory.hasMany(ModelPosts, {foreignKey: 'id_category'})

ModelPosts.belongsTo(PostCategory, {foreignKey: 'id_category'})
```

Сам запрос:

```
const allPosts = ModelPosts.findAll({ raw: true, include: { model: PostCategory} }).then(s => {
        console.log(s);
    })
```

Результат:

```
[
  {
    id_posts: 1,
    title: 'To be or not...',
    descr: 'авно выяснено, что при оценке дизайна и композиции читаемый текст мешает сосредоточиться. Lorem Ipsum используют потому, что тот обеспечивает более или менее стандартное заполнение шаблона, а также реальное распределение букв и пробелов в абзацах, которое не получается при простой дубликации "Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.. Здесь ваш текст.." Многие программы электронной вёрстки и редакторы HTML используют Lorem Ipsum в 
качестве текста по умолчанию, так что поиск по ключевым словам "lorem ipsum" сразу показывает, как много веб-страниц всё ещё дожидаются своего настоящего рождения. За прошедшие годы текст Lorem Ipsum получил много версий. Некоторые версии появились по ошибке, некоторые - намеренно (например, юмористические варианты).',
    id_category: 1,
    'post_category.id_category': 1,
    'post_category.name_category': 'Stars'
  },
  {
    id_posts: 3,
    title: 'Our first post',
    descr: 'Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.',
    id_category: 4,
    'post_category.id_category': 4,
    'post_category.name_category': 'Main news'
  },
  {
    id_posts: 4,
    title: 'Greeting',
    descr: '"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"',
    id_category: 4,
    'post_category.id_category': 4,
    'post_category.name_category': 'Main news'
  },
  {
    id_posts: 5,
    title: 'None',
    descr: 'None',
    id_category: 2,
    'post_category.id_category': 2,
    'post_category.name_category': 'Space'
  }
]
```

Comment: posts не в совсем стандартных скобках, "s" в конце добавляет по умолчанию к базе, мб стоит называть модель в одиночном числе.. в остальном ваш код корректен. post_category.id_category преобразуйте к имени, post_category.name_category as category_name

Comment: У меня вышло вытащить "post_category.id_category'" как s['post_category.name_category'], да я попробую преобразовать